# Build failed after add Cordova google admob Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, cordova-plugins

Used cordova plugin add [cordova.google.admob.plugin@2.7.7](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.git)

Plugin installed successful.

AndroidManifest.xml on uses-sdk tag

android:minSdkVersion="16"

android:targetSdkVersion="24"

Version Info

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7

OS: Windows 8

Node Version: v6.9.1

Ionic app build failed and generate error

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using following command to add the admob plugin:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro

This will let cordova CLI to handle dependency automatically. I tried and it works fine and i m also able to build platform. This command will automatically add `cordova-plugin-extension` plugin which takes care of dependencies